# Is it possible to show $(\lnot p \implies p) \implies p \vdash (\lnot \lnot p \implies p)$ in constructive logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, constructive-mathematics

I was given the task of showing that $(\lnot p \implies p)  \vdash p$ cannot be proven in constructive logic (that is, a system with no excluded middle, double negation, or $\lnot$-elimination).

I'm trying to assume that a proof for it exists and use that to show the law of excluded middle, or double negation to arrive at a contradiction. However, I'm a bit stuck and I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Definitions from which source are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Would you like the textbook that we are using with the rules or are there terms that I could expand on? I believe the notion of a "constructive proof" is a proof in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Yes, I mean textbook, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: We're using Lu's "Mathematical Logic for Computer Science".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can reduce as $$(\lnot p\to p)\to p,\lnot\lnot p\vdash p,$$ and then it suffices to show $$ (\lnot p\to p)\to p, \lnot\lnot p\vdash \lnot p \to p,$$ and again we can reduce that to $$ (\lnot p\to p)\to p,\lnot\lnot p, \lnot p\vdash p,$$ and we see we have a statement and its negation to the left of the turnstyle and we're done.

Observe that the left-hand side of the turnstyle in your title has the schematic form of proof by contradiction (note, nothing would change with the above proof if we replaced with $(\lnot p \to \bot)\to p$, and indeed this does not change the semantics of the statement, since we can prove $\bot$ from $\lnot p$ if and only if we can prove $p$ from $\lnot p$). Thus, we might expect this to be an equivalence. And it is... try to prove the other direction.

Comment: In the last step, it appears that you’re using a contradiction (or principle of explosion). I don’t think this is a part of our axiom system actually. Would there be a way to arrive at this result without generating a contradiction?

Comment: What rule of inference did you use to get the $\lnot p$ in step 2?

Comment: @DanielV What $\lnot p$? If we can show $$  (\lnot p\to p)\to p, \lnot\lnot p\vdash \lnot p \to p,$$ then we have $$ (\lnot p\to p)\to p, \lnot\lnot p\vdash p$$ by applying the first premise to the conculsion. (An instance of implication elimination / modus ponens/ function application / whatever.)

Comment: @learning_linalg If you want it in a particular system, you should say what system (this is why people were pestering you for references above... it's a common pitfall with these kinds of questions). I don't think this is provable without explosion (i.e. in minimal logic), so your system probably has the means to derive it. Above, you mentioned $\lnot$-elimination... how is that rule stated?

Comment: $\lnot$-elim is stated as if $\Sigma \lnot A \vdash B$ and $\Sigma \lnot A \vdash \lnot B$ then $\Sigma \vdash A$. This is not allowed in the system of the problem, but I realized that explosion is allowed, so this works great! As a side note, this has made me curious: would there be other approaches to showing this proposition is not provable under this system?

Comment: @learning_linalg Often when you want to prove something isn't provable, the easiest way is to use semantics. For instance, there is a Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic that you could produce a countermodel in.

Comment: @learning Another thought: for intuitionistic propositional logic (as opposed to predicate), validity is decidable, i.e. there is actually an algorithm that will determine if something is provable. For instance, if you type this into Coq and use the “tauto” tactic it will automatically generate a proof if one exists, and give an error if one doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{(\neg p\to p)\to p}{\fitch{\neg\neg p}{\fitch{\neg p}{\bot\\p}\\\neg p\to p\\p}\\\neg\neg p\to p}$

Take $(\neg p\to p)\to p$ as a premise.  Assume $\neg\neg p$ and $\neg p$.  Derive $p$ by explosion of the contradiction (EFQ). Deduce $\neg p\to p$ by discharging the second assumption (ie $\to$-introduction). Derive $p$ by modus ponens with the premise (or $\to$-elimination). Deduce $\neg\neg p\to p$ by discharging the first premise ($\to$-introduction).

This demonstrates that $(\neg p\to p)\to p\vdash \neg\neg p\to p$ may be derived using only rules of inference acceptable in constructive logic .

Therefore $(\neg\ p\to p)\to p$ can not be a theorem in constructive logic since it constructively entails $\neg\neg p\to p$, which is definitely not a theorem in constructive logic,

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but I had no idea EFQ was a valid prop in constructive logic, since no contradictions are allowed. Every proof I have done of that statement uses $\lnot$-elimination!

Comment: [The Hilbert Calculus for Constructive Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus)

Answer (score 0):

The question had been answered a while ago, but it's one that contains a bunch of red herrings and so I'll post the far broader principle at work:

- If $Q\to P$, then always $(N\to Q)\to(N\to P)$ as well as $(P\to p)\to(Q\to p)$.
- If $Q\to P$, then combining these we further get $\big((N\to P)\to p\big)\to\big((N\to Q)\to p\big)$.

Whenever $Q$ implies $p$, the formula also holds when setting $P=p$. Assuming explosion, $Q=\bot$ implies everything, and $p$ in particular. OP's result is obtained by further specializing with $N=\neg p$.